# An issue was found when checking AAR metadata: need android 34 complieSDK not 33

Tags: android, android-studio

Here I am facing an issue where I have just created a new project and rebuilt it and there was error

```
An issue was found when checking AAR metadata:
```

1. Dependency 'androidx.activity:activity:1.8.0' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
   Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-33.

   Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdk
   of at least 34, for example 34.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
   allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
   targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
   minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
   on).

I have not added anything new.
I also have reinstall the android studio and also tried with diffrent build version.
I am out of option to fixed this error.

project structure:
[Android Gradle Plugin Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgqTj.png)

build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.mamacode.ride'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mamacode.ride"
        minSdk 26
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

I am facing this error after I have update the android studio to giraffe

when i set the minCompileSDK to 34 is says can't find the sdk version.

Comment: I believe you must have compileSdk 34 and targetSDK 34 instead of 33, not the minSDK

Comment: @Ahmed no I have compileSDK 33 not 34, both the compileSDK and targetSDK is 33

Answer (score 0):

```
android {
namespace 'com.mamacode.ride'
compileSdk 34

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.mamacode.ride"
    minSdk 26
    targetSdk 34
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

Change **targetSdk** and **compileSdk** to **34**

Comment: You don't need to update the `targetSdk` at all - that can be done much later.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I have tried that before posting it here, when I change it, it says 

'Could not find compile target android-34 for modules :app'

Comment: @ZohnTungZang - do you have API 34 downloaded in the SDK Manager?

Comment: yeah, that was the error. I am so stupid. I though 33 is the latest.